# Category Page Custom Layout

Tags: pages, categories

I'm beginner in wordpress. I want to modify category page layout from this :

[image: Layout 1]

into this :

[image: Layout 2]

I'm using The7 theme.
I have read this [Category Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates), but still don't know how to. I have create category-news.php from category.php in wp-includes folder. I want to know how to : 
- adding custom header in category page
- change the content layout from grid (3 post) to list (4 post)
- remove Leave a comment, Category Name and Author from under the title of the article/post and adding the text / post content (Contrary ... )
I'll modify pagination from CSS.

Comment: That is more then one question ;) In addition please show the code you tried to write yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the options from this theme. Probably you can set all this in the theme options.

Accordion to the demo pages from The7 theme page you can choose for a list layout i.o a grid layout
http://the7.dream-demo.com/blog/blog-list/5-blog-list/

Comment: Thank you @BlueCloudNL. You are my savior. I use a template themes that you demonstrated. The name of the theme template is Blog - list. The rest I did change the css and the following files : theme-setup.php, post-navigation.php, html-helpers.php and blog-post-content-part.php. Here is the result [http://i.imgur.com/Aetanz4.png]. Sorry I have to remove header and footer from image.